# Index disappears after grouping a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, group-by

I have the following **pandas series**:

```
Reducedset['% Renewable']
```

Which gives me:

```
Asia           China                 19.7549
               Japan                 10.2328
               India                 14.9691
               South Korea           2.27935
               Iran                  5.70772
North America  United States          11.571
               Canada                61.9454
Europe         United Kingdom        10.6005
               Russian Federation    17.2887
               Germany               17.9015
               France                17.0203
               Italy                 33.6672
               Spain                 37.9686
Australia      Australia             11.8108
South America  Brazil                 69.648
Name: % Renewable, dtype: object
```

I then sorted this series into 5 bins:

```
binning = pd.cut(Top15['% Renewable'],5)
```

Which gives me:

```
Asia           China                 (15.753, 29.227]
               Japan                  (2.212, 15.753]
               India                  (2.212, 15.753]
               South Korea            (2.212, 15.753]
               Iran                   (2.212, 15.753]
North America  United States          (2.212, 15.753]
               Canada                (56.174, 69.648]
Europe         United Kingdom         (2.212, 15.753]
               Russian Federation    (15.753, 29.227]
               Germany               (15.753, 29.227]
               France                (15.753, 29.227]
               Italy                 (29.227, 42.701]
               Spain                 (29.227, 42.701]
Australia      Australia              (2.212, 15.753]
South America  Brazil                (56.174, 69.648]
Name: % Renewable, dtype: category
Categories (5, interval[float64]): [(2.212, 15.753] < (15.753, 29.227] < (29.227, 42.701] <
                                    (42.701, 56.174] < (56.174, 69.648]]
```

I then grouped this binned data in order to calculate the number of countries in each bin:

```
 Reduced = Reducedset.groupby(binning)['% Renewable'].agg(['count'])
```

Which gives me:

```
% Renewable
(2.212, 15.753]     7
(15.753, 29.227]    4
(29.227, 42.701]    2
(42.701, 56.174]    0
(56.174, 69.648]    2
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

However, the index has **disappeared** and I still want to keep the index for the 'continents' (the outer index).

Thus, on the very left of the (% Renewable) column it **should say:**

```
Asia
North America 
Europe
Australia
South America
```

When I try doing that by:

```
print(Reducedset['% Renewable'].groupby([Reducedset['% Renewable'].index.get_level_values(0),pd.cut(Reducedset['% Renewable'],5)]).count())
```

**It works!**

Problem solved!

Comment: @Ben.T in effect, I want this output:    

                             count
binning                
(2.212, 15.753]       7
(15.753, 29.227]      4
(29.227, 42.701]      2
(56.174, 69.648]      2

But with the Continent index included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume the following data:

```
np.random.seed(1)
s = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0,10, 16), 
              index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([list('aaaabbccdddddeee'), 
                                               list('abcdefghijklmnop')]))
```

What you are looking IIUC is then

```
print(s.groupby([s.index.get_level_values(0), #that is the continent for you
                 pd.cut(s, 5)]) #that is the binning you created
       .count())
a  (-0.009, 1.8]    0
   (1.8, 3.6]       0
   (3.6, 5.4]       2
   (5.4, 7.2]       0
   (7.2, 9.0]       2
b  (-0.009, 1.8]    2
   (1.8, 3.6]       0
   (3.6, 5.4]       0
   (5.4, 7.2]       0
   (7.2, 9.0]       0
c  (-0.009, 1.8]    1
   (1.8, 3.6]       0
   (3.6, 5.4]       0
   (5.4, 7.2]       1
   (7.2, 9.0]       0
d  (-0.009, 1.8]    0
   (1.8, 3.6]       1
   (3.6, 5.4]       2
   (5.4, 7.2]       1
   (7.2, 9.0]       1
e  (-0.009, 1.8]    0
   (1.8, 3.6]       2
   (3.6, 5.4]       1
   (5.4, 7.2]       0
   (7.2, 9.0]       0
dtype: int64
```

Comment: when I try: print(Reducedset['% Renewable'].groupby([Reducedset['% Renewable'].index.get_level_values(0),pd.cut(Reducedset['% Renewable'],5)])), I get: <pandas.core.groupby.generic.SeriesGroupBy object at 0x10dcac1c0> @Ben.T

Comment: ahh yes! Forgot that! Silly me!

Comment: my only issue now is that the count column has no column label, how can I add a label 'count' to that column?

Comment: thank you, actually the reason I wanted to index the counts is because I want to remove the bins where count = 0, is there another way I can do this without converting to a dataframe?

Comment: @Caledonian26 let's say the series with the zeros is called `s_count`, then you could do `s_count[s_count>0]`